# Exclude client from sync with roaming profile?

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, roaming-profile

is it possible to exclude one machine from syncing its profile with the server?

The situation is as follows:

Our CEO wants to use her semi-private laptop in our network, which means she wants to be able to log in with her account (to be able to access files and all) but does not want her (private) profile to be synced.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an OU (by using Active Directory Users and Computers). After you join her computer to the domain, move her computer into the new OU. Then create a group policy, applying it to only that OU, prohibiting roaming profiles. That will effectively cause that computer to never use her roaming profile, and always use only her local profile.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is waht you want:
Go to system properties, advanced tab.
Click Advanced, click Settings from User profiles' section.
Select her username and change the status to Local.
The previous status should be roaming.

BR
Paul

Comment: Is this a per-user-setting or per-machine-setting? Because her desktop PC (same login) should use a roaming profile.